# Joomla change favicon jdoc

Tags: templates, joomla, favicon

I have two questions:

a) How can i acess Joomla template's folder in the website so i can see where some images are placed and replace it.

b) How do i change my template's website favicon ? Website head is something like this:

```
<head>
  <jdoc:include type="head" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" /
</head>
```

The favicon part is inside the "jdoc: include", which i don't know how to acess it. I would like some help on how to acess here to change favicon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is to look in the /templates folder. That folder contains a series of folders that represent the templates on your system. If you want to change where your images are stored, you will need to update the template you are using to point to the new location.

The  directive has built into it instructions to display the favicon.ico file that is located in your active template folder. So you don't really need to change the location of the favicon, just put the image you want to display in your template folder and name it favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

a) Use ftp-cliet to browse your site folders. For example [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php).

b) No favicon isn't assigned inside `<jdoc:include type="head" />`. If it is not assigned explicitly, default favicon is used. In your template after code you have posted add following code

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/__your__template_folder__/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

and upload image `favicon.ico` into your template folder.

I hope it will be helpfull.